# Ubuntu "gem install rails" fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu-14.04

I'm on ubuntu working with rails here What do I get when I try to install gem?
Here it is

```
$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.1.0 directory.
```

what should I have to do to get it to work?

Comment: Are you using rvm or rbenv?

Comment: That is really the preferred way, using `sudo` is not even though at first glance it seems to work quite nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal user accounts generally don't have the ability (often called permissions or privilege) to write to files in the root (starts with "/") directory.

You need to elevate your privilege to that of a superuser, aka the root user. The most common way is to type

```
sudo [the command you wanted to run]
```

So type

```
sudo gem install rails
```

The system will ask you for your password and if it's your first time running sudo, it will warn you to be careful. :)

Edit: Listen to iceman's comment about using rvm or rbenv instead. Even though using sudo works for this, that does not mean it is the best option.

Comment: Using rvm or rbenv to install rails per user is the preferred method, not to force things with sudo.